# Still can't have long file paths after enabling them

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

Ran into the 260 character file path limit today, did some googling and found [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/) article describing how to remove the limit. Followed the steps for group policy (I have Windows 10 Pro) and then restarted.

**Edit:** looked in the registry path mentioned in the article. The value is already set to 1

However, the problem still occurs, and I can't create the files because the "filepaths(s) would be too long".

I'm running Windows 10 Pro Build 14393.953.

Comment: I probably depends upon what you are trying to do.  Remember what it says within that tutorial:  *"There is one caveat. This new setting won’t necessarily work with every application out there, but it will work with most."*

Comment: @Run5k I'm just using the file explorer to try and copy a directory inside a fairly deep file tree. Would expect it to work with file explorer. On a broader scale I want it to work with Visual studio, which being a Microsoft product I'd also expect to work, but that isn't as important.

Comment: From the article you referenced, try the registry fix as well.

Comment: @Steven see edit.

Comment: Yes, I would expect it to work with `File Explorer`, also... but unfortunately, it doesn't.